# How do I install plugins for vim on my university server?

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to install some plugins on my university server, just for my account. However, it's different from my machine which I have direct access to everything. I don't know where to put the plugin in. For example, right now I want to install omnicppcomplete for me to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put vim plugins in your home directory under the .vim/plugins folder

so ~/.vim/plugins is where you want to install them too

Comment: There's no .vim folder under my home folder. Must I create them?

Comment: Yeppers and then create a .vim/plugin in that

Comment: I did as you said and nothing happened.

Comment: what is the plugin you are trying to install?